# Ordering vector lists in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list with several registers from other lists. I put an index at the beginning of each element so that I can order it later, for writing purposes.

```
reg = index + ";" + cell[1] + ";" + hour + ";" + cell[0] + ";" + text[1] + ";"
```

At the end, `reg` should give something like this:

```
['5;01;11.32;RN_RT;Prep;', '9;02;2.12;ING;Prep;', '1;06;4.23;ING;Rec;']
```

Is there a way to order/sort it using the index at the beginning?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn Pandas!

Comment: use the index as key to a dict: `reg = {}` and `reg[index] = ...`  then: `[reg[index] for index in sorted(reg.keys())]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort with `key=lambda s: int(s.split(';', 1)[0])`.

Comment: I have never used lambda, can you explain a bit how it would work for the sorting?

Comment: @JoshuaCazares If you've never used lambdas, [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Comment: See also [Why are Python lambdas useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small helper function:

```
def by_index(x):
    return int(x.split(';', 1)[0])
```

and use it for sorting:

```
L = ['5;01;11.32;RN_RT;Prep;','9;02;2.12;ING;Prep;','1;06;4.23;ING;Rec;']

sorted(L, key=by_index)

['1;06;4.23;ING;Rec;', '5;01;11.32;RN_RT;Prep;', '9;02;2.12;ING;Prep;']
```

The function [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) takes the keyword argument `key`:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

This function is called for each element in the list. So:

```
int(x.split(';', 1)[0])
```

splits off the value before the first `;` and turns it into an integer. This is the index. This index will be used for sorting (the sorting key) but the sort result is the list elements in the order of the index.

`lambda` is just another way to define a function without using `def`. It is limited to expressions but can be used inline.